# Setting RootViewController in Appdelegate

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard

I have **storyboard** in my application, but i don't want to set the `Main storyboard file base name` in **info.plist**, as well as I don't want to set the entry point i.e `Is Initial View Controller` in **storyboard** for any viewcontroller scene.

Though I want to launch the app with some scene from the storyboard, but all shows me a black screen.

When I tried

```
let testob:testClass = testClass()
self.window?.rootViewController = testob
```

in AppDelegate, it didn't worked and got the same black screen.

But when I set the `Main storyboard file base name` in info.plist, and the entry point i.e `Is Initial View Controller` in storyboard every thing works.

Is there any solution to do so?

Comment: Check the following link if it works for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26514028/programatically-setting-root-view-controller-in-swift

Answer (score 12):

You need to instantiate the window and make it key and visible.

```
let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
self.window = UIWindow(frame: bounds)
self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can load a particular view controller from storyboard.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896406/how-can-i-load-storyboard-programmatically-from-class).

Example:

`window?.rootViewController = initialViewController()`

where

```
    private func initialViewController() -> UIViewController {
        if isUserLoggedIn {
            return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoadingViewControllerIdentifier")
        } else {
            return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewControllerIdentifier")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

After setting self.window?.rootViewController = testob, you have to do the following

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]
```

Also, initialize the viewController from storyboard using appropriate method